# io.on is not working while making connection using socket.io in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, sockets, laravel-5, socket.io-redis, ioredis

i am facing problem (i really frustrated), while i connecting the io.on function. i am using express,ioredis and socket.io. redis working properly but socket.io is not working. it is'nt working.please help.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

//port connection
server.listen(3000);
console.log('server listening 3000');

//redis sub (working fine)
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function () {
    console.log('Redis: test-channel subscribed');
});

//this code is not working (stop execution)
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("new client connected");
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("new client connected");

    redis.subscribe('message');
    console.log("redis start");

    //send message to frontend
    redis.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("mew message in queue "+ message + "channel");
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });
    //close socket
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redis.quit();
        console.log('redis disconnected!');
    });

});
```

Client side

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

   <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            $(".progress-bar").css('width',+data+'%');
            alert('connection established');
            $("#messages").append( "<p>"+data+"</p>" );
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you change `io.on` to `io.sockets.on` ? and remove duplicated code.

Comment: i already tried this, but this does not work.

Comment: even that too ? your client config ?

Comment: both are not working :- io.sockets.on, CreateServer

Comment: can you post your client side config ?

Comment: please check client side script

Comment: hmm its not showing _new client connected_ in your console ? just put `var socket = io.connect()`

Comment: in server side script?

Comment: yes in server console it show somthing ? var socket = io.connect() in client side

Comment: i am getting error - TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'connect'

Comment: on browser right ?

Comment: no, on console. (i just want a message on console :-  console.log("new client connected");

Comment: dude which console ? browser console or server side console ?

Comment: i think client side code is correct, problem in server side (io.on)

Comment: server side console.

Comment: its `io.sockets.on` not `io.on`

Comment: io.sockets.on also not working.can you please post full edited server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // it was require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);
```

Client side

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("new client connected");
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error msg
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
can you please say an solution

Answer (score 0):

const { Server } = require("socket.io")
const io = new Server(server)

Comment: Hi @AnujSaklani, If you could edit you post so that the code is in a snippet (select the code and `ctrl + k`)
Also you it would be awesome if you could add some explanation, it would greatly improve the readability and quality of your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).